# Pick unique child list items using NBuilder

Tags: c#, mocking, nbuilder

I'm using NBuilder for mocking up test data for a object graph of owner and cars.
So the relationship between a single owner and cars is unique.

```
Owner 1 
 - Car 2
 - Car 3
Owner 2
 - Car 4
 - Car 5
```

So I have used the following code:

```
var owners = (List<Owner>)Builder<Owner>.CreateListOfSize(2)
                            .All()
                                .Do(d => d.Tranche = (List<Car>)Pick<Car>.UniqueRandomList(2).From(cars))
                            .Build();
```

However, what I get is that same car is being picked up for the multiple owners:

```
Owner 1 
 - Car 2
 - Car 4
Owner 2
 - Car 4
 - Car 5
```

Is there anyway to handle this ? so that the relationship for the mock data is unique.

Comment: How have you resolved this?